# SUM function does not return decimal

Tags: sql-server, sum, decimal

I need your help:

I want to get the SUM of the the Amount field, it contains decimal values but I get just the `INTEGER` part and I need the `DECIMAL` too:

```
DECLARE @TOTAL AS DECIMAL(13,2)

SET @Total = (SELECT SUM(Amount)
              FROM t_DownPmtTrans
              WHERE MortgageID = @MortgageID 
                AND DatePaid IS NULL 
                AND SchedPayment IS NOT NULL)
```

I have tried with a CURSOR but I get the same:

```
OPEN dpt_cursor 
SET @Total= 0.0

FETCH NEXT FROM dpt_cursor INTO @DownPmtTransID, @Amount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS= 0 
BEGIN

   PRINT @Amount
   SET @Total = (@Total + @Amount)

   FETCH NEXT FROM dpt_cursor
     INTO @DownPmtTransID, @Amount
END 

RETURN  @Total* (-1)
CLOSE dpt_cursor 
DEALLOCATE dpt_cursor
```

Thanks!!

Comment: When you declare @Total, what data type is it?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Plelase edit your question and replace the sql tag with the specific tag for your implementation.

Comment: @Barmar `@@FETCH_STATUS` indicates SQL Server.

Comment: I declared @Total as DECIMAL(13,2)

Comment: Please show us **sample data** and what SUM() you're expecting and what you're getting. I cannot reproduce any problem - `SUM()` of `DECIMAL(13,2)` values returns a nice `DECIMAL(13,2)` value, too.

Comment: Could your Amount field in your t_DownPmtTrans table not be a decimal?  I can't replicate with test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08e22/2

Answer (score 3):

You need to set precision and scale rather than size
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var outputParameter = new SqlParameter
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    ParameterName = "your parameter name in your stored procedure",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal,
    Precision = 13,
    Scale = 2
};
```

Declare an array of SQL parameters and add the parameter to it

```
var parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
parameters[0] = outputParameter
```

declare a command object

```
var command = new SqlCommand (); //don't forget everything else
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "stored procedure name"
command.Parameters.AddRange (parameters);
```

Execute your command

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
```

now read the value from the parameters collection

```
var value = (decimal) command.Parameters[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx), if the expression is `decimal`, `sum` will return `decimal(38, s)`. Make sure the datatype is of `amount` is `decimal`. Or try to convert it to `decimal` using `cast` or `convert`. This options may help you.

Comment: Sql SUM() returns INT even if the datatype for amount (in my case it was the column type) is decimal.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate either, but in any event converting the column you're summing to the datatype of your variable should get you what you want. The only reason this wouldn't be the case is if "Amount" is an int...

```
DECLARE @TOTAL AS DECIMAL(13,2)

SET     @Total =   (SELECT  SUM(Convert(DECIMAL(13,2),Amount))
                    FROM    t_DownPmtTrans
                    WHERE   MortgageID = @MortgageID 
                    AND     DatePaid IS NULL 
                    AND     SchedPayment IS NOT NULL)
```

Since the issue is outside of SQL I did a quick search and found this: http://forums.asp.net/t/33723.aspx/1

According to it this is a known issue. I looked around a little more and while this guy didn't say it helped I would suggest creating a SqlParameter object so you can set the precision property of the object and then pass that in your Add method.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, the problem is in my .NET code, still dont know exactly why. Im getting an Integer but if i query directly in the database i get a Decimal.
The code im implementing:

Comment: This is my code:
 Try
            conexion.Open()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Auth_Reference", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = authReference
            Dim retval As New SqlParameter("@Total", SqlDbType.Decimal, 10)
            retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
            cmd.Parameters.Add(retval)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Try
                totalSchedPayments = (cmd.Parameters.Item("@Total").Value)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Catch ex As SqlException

Comment: @EmmanuelSantana I added some additional information. I think the issue is that the SqlParameter object you're passing to your SqlParameterCollection does not have the precision defined so it defaults to zero and rounds to an int.

Comment: Hello @Love2Learn I have already set the precision but i get the same. I noticed, when i Execute the Stored Procedure it does not return the decimals, but when i execute the SELECT statement it does!

DECLARE @ return_value DECIMAL(13,2)

EXEC @ return_value = [dbo].[sp_TarjetaObtenerTotalSchedPayments]
  @ Auth_Reference = N'59384'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @ return_value

GO

Comment: Where do you set the precision? I see that you have the size set to 10, but I don't see anything about precision. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Comment: I've found the problem. you CANT return a DECIMAL from a Stored Procedure. Thanks For your help anyway. I set an OUTPUT parameter instead a RETURN. Greetings